# Compiling latex into a pdf with PHP

Tags: php, latex

I'm trying to get PHP to execute this command: `/usr/bin/pdflatex --interaction batchmode $path.tex` with shell_exec but getting an error from pdflatex:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) restricted \write18 enabled. entering extended mode ! I can't write on file 'tmp_1439479712.log'. (Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is'.log') Please type another transcript file name

I tried making a file with `shell_exec("echo test > $path.test")` and that worked so www-data can write files to the directory, I also tried running pdflatex in the cli as a user similar to www-data and that worked, what am I missing?

Comment: note `file 'tmp_...'`. it can't write a temporary file it needs, so your test is irrelevant - you're not testing in the same location or on the same file. you need to figure out where it's trying to create/use this temp file.l

Comment: The filename is from me, I save the .tex file as tmp_(timestamp).tex and then pdflatex tries to make tmp_(timestamp).log tmp_(timestamp).aux and finally tmp_(timestamp).pdf in the same directory that I saved the original .tex file (this I know from running pdflatex on the command line)

Comment: then why is it complaining `tmp.log`, while your command line says `$path.tex`?